# Extension Method With Generic Parameter To Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

The code below does not compile:

```
 public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static Bar<M> Convert<T,M>(this Foo<T> list)
        {
            return new Bar<M>();
        }
    }


    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo<int> foo = new Foo<int>();

            foo.Convert<double>();
        }
    }
```

I have to explicitely specify Foo's generic type:

```
foo.Convert<int, double>();
```

Specifying the type during method call would not be necessary, if the extension method had a single generic parameter.

Why? Can I create such an extension method that does not require me to specify Foo's parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why?

Type argument inference is all or nothing: you've got to either specify all the type arguments, or none of them, on each method call.

The `M` type parameter can't be inferred, because it doesn't occur anywhere in the parameter list.

A few options:

- Chain two methods together, so that the first can use type inference and the second will let you specify the type argument for `M`:

  ```
  Bar<double> bar = foo.CreateConverter()   // Implicitly CreateConverter<int>
                       .ConvertTo<double>() // Specify that you want a Bar<double>
  ```

  This would require a new intervening type, e.g. `Converter<T>` to be returned by `CreateConverter`. That would have a regular instance method of `ConvertTo<M>`.
- Add a parameter of type `M` to the `Convert` method:

  ```
  public static Bar<M> Convert<T, M>(this Foo<T> list, M ignored)
  ```

  ... you can then call the method as:

  ```
  Bar<double> bar = foo.Convert(default(double));
  ```

  That's somewhat smelly, admittedly.
- Don't use an extension method, but a regular static generic method in a generic type - where both the type and the method have a single type parameter:

  ```
  public static class Converters<M>
  {
      public static Bar<M> Create<T>(Foo<T> foo) { ... }
  }
  ```

  then invoke it as:

  ```
  Bar<double> bar = Converters<double>.Create(foo);
  ```

  The type argument for the *method* can be inferred from `foo`, and you're specifying the type argument for the *type* explicitly.